# ActionController: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with action in my controller - when I call link_to in view with destroy action there is an error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError

No route matches {:controller=>"user_votes", :action=>"destroy", :recipient_uid=>2911238}
```

routes:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :users
  resources :votes 
  resources :user_votes
  root 'main#home'

end
```

user_vote_controller:

```
class UserVotesController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
        @user_vote = UserVote.find_by(params[:recipient_uid])
        @user_vote.destroy
        redirect_to root_url
    end

end
```

view file:

```
 = link_to 'Delete', {controller: "user_votes", action: "destroy", recipient_uid: friend.uid}, method: "delete"
```

Can you show me where I made a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the contents of config/routes.rb please.

Comment: also, the controller/action hash syntax for `link_to` is antiquated, you should use the route helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource url for the destroy function is actually 'user_votes/:id'. So you need to pass in the `:id` parameter when you call the link_to helper

```
 = link_to 'Delete', {controller: "user_votes", action: "destroy", recipient_uid: friend.uid, id: some_id}, method: "delete"
```

Replace `some_id` with the actual resource id.